# OpenCV: output image is blue

Tags: c++, image, opencv, opencv3.0

so i'm making this project where i'm making the reflection of an image on OpenCV (without using the flip function), and the only problem (i think) to finish it, is that the image that is suppose to come out reflected, is coming out as all blue.

The code i have (i took out the usual part, the problem should be around here):

```
Mat imageReflectionFinal = Mat::zeros(Size(220,220),CV_8UC3);

for(unsigned int r=0; r<221; r++)
    for(unsigned int c=0; c<221; c++) {
       Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(r,c);
       imageReflectionFinal.at<Vec3b>(r,c) = (uchar)(c, -r + (220)/2);
    }

    ///displays images
    imshow( "Original Image", image );
    imshow("Reflected Image", imageReflectionFinal);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's also off-by-one error in both of the for loops, which will cause you to access memory past the end of the pixel buffer. `Size(220,220)` means that the maximum column (as well as row) number is 219, not 220.

Comment: What do you expect `(uchar)(c, -r + (220)/2)` to do?

Answer (score 3):

There are some problems with your code. As pointed out, your iteration variables go beyond the actual image dimensions. Do not use hardcoded bounds, you can use `inputImage.cols` and `inputImage.rows` instead to obtain the image dimensions.

There’s the variable (a BGR Vec3b) that is set but not used - `Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(r,c);`

Most importantly, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. The line `(uchar)(c, -r + (220)/2);` does not give out much info. Also, which direction are you flipping the original image around? X or Y axis?

Here’s a possible solution to flip your image in the X direction:

```
//get input image:
cv::Mat testMat = cv::imread( "lena.png" );

//Get the input image size:
int matCols = testMat.cols;
int matRows = testMat.rows;

//prepare the output image:
cv::Mat imageReflectionFinal = cv::Mat::zeros( testMat.size(), testMat.type() );

//the image will be flipped around the x axis, so the "target"
//row will start at the last row of the input image:
int targetRow = matRows-1;

//loop thru the original image, getting the current pixel value:
for( int r = 0; r < matRows; r++ ){
    for( int c = 0; c < matCols; c++ ) {
        //get the source pixel:
        cv::Vec3b sourcePixel = testMat.at<cv::Vec3b>( r , c );
        //source and target columns are the same:
        int targetCol = c;
        //set the target pixel
        imageReflectionFinal.at<cv::Vec3b>( targetRow , targetCol ) = sourcePixel;
    }
    //for every iterated source row, decrease the number of
    //target rows, as we are flipping the pixels in the x dimension:
    targetRow--;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just to clear it up, my question about that statement was to get the OP to think about what that statement actually means in C++ as it is written. | Good work on the answer. :)

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for the complete answer! I didn't know i could get the rows and cols like that, thanks for that, also the way you posted to prepare the output image seems way better.

What i'm trying to do at `(uchar)(c, -r + (220)/2)` is apply a formula of (y,−x+ 2x0), to make the image flip, my objective is to then try to also make it flip horizontally applying (−y+ 2y0,x). (more on new comment, hit characters limit)

Comment: At this point i tried to adapt some of your code to mine, it happens that if i leave it `Vec3b sourcePixel = image.at<Vec3b>(r,c);
                    imageReflectionFinal.at<Vec3b>(r, c) = (uchar)(c, -r + (220)/2);` i get the blue image i got before, but if i change it to                     `imageReflectionFinal.at<Vec3b>(rows, cols) = (uchar)(cols, -rows + (220)/2)` i get a blank image (all black). The blue image i got before, had a line going horizontally.